# How to determine how long a song is using winmm.dll?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, pinvoke, media

I've [P/Invoked the mciSendString method from WinMM.dll](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winmm.mciSendString):

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
private static extern long mciSendString(string strCommand, StringBuilder strReturn,
                                         int iReturnLength, IntPtr hwndCallback);
```

I can play, pause, and stop songs (I can also open/close the CD drive, but that's not important). Now I want my user to be able to skip to a certain part in a song (e.g. 1:21). I've looked at the [seek functions documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713245(VS.85).aspx) and it seems pretty staightforward except that I can't figure out how long a song is. Does a command/method exist to do this in WinMM?

Comment: Is there any reason why you use the MCI API and not DirectShow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would probably be something like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);
mciSendString("status mediafile length", sb, 128, IntPtr.Zero);
long songlength = Convert.ToUInt64(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks. BTW great Stackoverflow/Serverfault sidebar gadget.