# how to play a mp3 file from the middle

Tags: c#, mp3

```
mciSendStringi("","","","");
```

I used the above function to play a mp3 file. Now I want to play
the mp3 file from the middle (i.e) if the file is 5:32 minutes long I want to play it from 2:00 minutes. Can any help me how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
long millisecs = 120000;
long status = mciSendString(String.Format("seek MediaFile to {0}", millisecs), null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
```

To determine the length of the file, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033559/how-to-determine-how-long-a-song-is-using-winmm-dll/1033639#1033639)